# JavaScript seem just to react after MouseMove

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, infragistics

probably the strangst thing I've ever seen: I want to load a grid after the document is loaded. Since the grid (infragistics) seems to delay, I set a interval, in the interval I try to get the needed element, if I cant find it, I wait another 500 ms:

```
    function trySetEditMode(obj) {
        var testObj = $('#' + obj.btnId).parents("tr[type='row']").get(0);

        if (testObj && testObj._object){
            clearInterval(_intervalId);
```

The funny thing is: Even if I see the with the IE debugging tool the row is there, it justdoenst find it. It works just when I move arround with the mouse. This effect seems totally random.

Has anyone an idea how this is possible? I tried to tinker arorund with .focus, .blur etc, but nothing seems to work.

btw: obj is a custom object from me, the button id is the clientid of the button and is there. For example:

```
$('#' + obj.btnId).parents('tr').length
```

returns a length.

Can this be a bug from the infragistics control? If yes, how could I simulate this mouseMove?

Best regards

Matthias

Comment: Doesn't this grid have an callback for when it finishes loading?

Comment: ClientEvents-Initialize seems to early, ClientEvents-DataBound doesnt shoot, probably because I bind in the server-side, RowRendered doesnt shoot was well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating the row objects is costly on the client and as such they are created on demand to avoid a large performance hit if all row objects were created initially.  The actual creation of these objects is on mouse over or when you use the get_row() method that is provided as part of the [client side object model](http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/ASPNET/Current/CLR4.0/?page=Web_Client_Side_Object_Model_CSOM_Reference_Guide.html).  As such the recommended approach is to use the client side object model to get a reference to the row, for example the following will get the first row:

```
var grid = $find("webDataGrid1");  

var row = grid.get_rows().get_row(0);
```

Comment: So I'd need to save the index of the row to get it and work with it? I debugged the javascript of the grid and all I found was the initialization at the mouse-over. I'm still surprised there is no proper method to load all rows, and I'm even more surprised the support of infragistics couldnt give me this informations.

Comment: Why would you want to initialize all of the rows?  Is it necessary for anything that you are doing?  The grid functionality doesn't require it be done initially and if some of the rows aren't actually accessed by the user then there is no reason to initialize them.

Answer (score 0):

probably someoneelse will have this problem as well with infragistics webdatagrid:
Sidenote: I cant believe the ig support couldnt tell me that:
The Grid is kinda lazyLoaded, the dom gets loaded but the ig relevant attributes AND the object behind just get loaded when you go with the mouse over. So it didnt matter how long I waited, the object wasnt just there.

Since I had no time to get a proper solution, I basically fired manually the mouse over event on a cell. It doesnt matter on what you do this, but I tested it with the first one and it worked proper.

```
            //The grid doesnt load data (except the first row) until the mouse did hover over it
            //Get a cell, and hover over it
            var parentTd = btn.parents('td').first();
            var cell = parentTd.siblings()[0];
            var rows = $find('dgrRoles').get_rows();
            if (cell && rows) {
                cell.target = cell;
                rows._onMouseOver(cell);
            }
```